# textbox autocomplete

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, textbox, autocomplete

how do i make an autocomplete textbox in asp?
but i need to get the autocomplete data by querying the database. 
I dont really know how to explain this, sory if theres not enough detail. 
i cant use ajax, because i think i will have compability issues with my old app.
so im thinking of doing this using java script. or is there a way to do this by using .net?
im using C# for codebehind. thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's going to be a lot of effort without using some third party autocomplete I think - not sure what you mean by 'I can't use ajax', but how about using the [ASP.NET AJAX autocomplete control](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx), setting the `ServiceMethod` property to a static Page Method in your code behind? That keeps it contained within your page at least.

The Page Method can go off to your database, and return a String[] of results.

If you decide to use it, you'll need to set the `EnablePageMethods` property to `true` in the `<asp:ScriptManager>` control.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is JavaScript.  It's JavaScript using the XMLHttpRequest object to make the asynchronous request.  [Here's an article about it and ASP.NET](http://www.dotnetjunkies.ddj.com/Article/E80EC96F-1C32-4855-85AE-9E30EECF13D7.dcik).

If you want to know more about AJAX, (**A**synchronous **J**avaScript **a**nd **X**ML), I'd check out [Wikipedia first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX).  If you want books on it, there are a ton.  I recommend *[Programming ASP.NET AJAX](http://safari.oreilly.com/9780596514242)* by Christian Wenz (O'Reilly And Associates).

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to uses ajax library, try jquery

there are many plugin autocomplete or suggest textbox for jquery
try this one
http://www.vulgarisoip.com/2007/08/06/jquerysuggest-11/

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET AJAX framework works for ASP.NET 2.0 & above. As such it will not work in Visual Studio 2003 environment.

Anthem.NET is a free, cross-browser AJAX toolkit/framework for the ASP.NET development environment that works with both ASP.NET 1.1 and 2.0 -
http://sourceforge.net/projects/anthem-dot-net

For your autocomplete requirement, you can consider using the jQuery Autocomplete Plugin

It requires very less programming. Check the demo & code sample here - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

It's autocomplete() method takes a URL or array to populate your autocompletion list. You can pass the URL of the page that fetches the results from the database directly.